# How long should I wait for a virus to be removed before attempting to shut the process down and try again?

Tags: anti-virus, ms-security-essentials

After a 7 hour scan of over 200GB of backed up information on my external hard drive MSE found a single virus Win32/cmdow.A within a rar installer of an open source expansion of a game .. and it has now gotten stuck at the 75% mark during the infections removal.

Comment: apearently only a couple minutes longer than I could wait before getting worried.. Its done =) LOL

Answer (score 2):

Use Resource Monitor to see if MSE process is reading the file, or consuming memory. If it isn't I would assume MSE has crashed, and kill the process, reboot and try the scan again.

I would also look online to see if you can confirm if the open source package does have a virus.